# Ignoring error in timer MATLAB

Tags: matlab, timer

I have a code that processes a video in real time from a webcam, while performing some operations to it, reading each frame.

For that, I use the function "timer". Sometimes, and for strange reasons, I get an error such as:

Error while evaluating TimerFcn for timer 'timer-77'

Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

Is there a way to ignore this error and continue with the next frame?

```
 function DetectTarget2()
    clc;imaqreset;close all;
try
    % For linux
    Vid = videoinput('linuxvideo', 1);
catch
    try
        % For mac
        Vid = videoinput('macvideo', 1);
    catch
        errordlg('No webcam available');
    end
end

set(Vid,'FramesPerTrigger',1);  %capture 1 frame every time Vid is triggered
set(Vid,'TriggerRepeat',Inf);   %infinite amount of triggers
set(Vid,'ReturnedColorSpace','RGB');
triggerconfig(Vid, 'Manual');   %trigger Vid manually within program

t = timer('TimerFcn',@dispim, 'Period', 0.04,...
    'executionMode','fixedRate');

function dispim(~,~)
        trigger(Vid)%trigger Vid to capture image
        im=getdata(Vid,1);
        detector = vision.CascadeObjectDetector('Cascade1Matlab.xml');
        bbox = step(detector, im); 

% CALCULATIONS

degrees=result;
end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid stopping due to errors by wrapping code in `try-catch` blocks:

```
function dispim(~,~)
    try
      %# code goes here
    catch me
      %# you get here if an error happens
      %# use the catch-block to make sure subsequent iterations will run fine
      disp(me.message); %# display the error message
    end
end
```